# Accidentally overriding getter with swift extension - Only during runtime when app enters foreground again

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

> The last 2 days i brooded over a strange behavior i found in my iOS app. It was one of these moments when you start to have doubts about everything. I found the problem and fixed it. But i want to write this here to search for answers and gain knowledge about the system behind.

I am the developer of "Controller for HomeKit", an app to control HomeKit devices. In HomeKit you have **HMActionSet**s to execute many changes at once. *E.g. Turn on all lights.*

Executing **HMActionSet** is a basic functionality and worked **always**. Here with a swipe of UITableViewCell.

```
let performAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: AppStrings.Actions.perform, handler: { (ac: UIContextualAction, view: UIView, success: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) in
        self.home?.executeActionSet(selectedActionSet, completionHandler: { (error: Error?) in
            if let err = error {
                UIApplication.printToConsole(text: err)
                success(false)
                return
            }
            success(true)
        })
    })
```

**BUT** suddenly it stopped working flawlessly with a new development version. It took me a while to reproduce the situation, when it wasn't executing the action set.

- Every time i start the app from scratch, **everything works**.
- If i execute the HMActionSet right after navigating from the previous UIViewController, **everything works**. (Most common use case)
- **It stops working** when being in the view, press the home button, reentering the app. After that all executions won't work, until going one view backwards and forward again.

---

Console logs this error:

```
Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=2 "Object not found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Object not found.}
```

I walked backwards every commit until the problem was solved. After digging in the dark in a too big commit, i found the root cause.

**But why am i not getting compile errors? Why does going to the home screen breaks it?**

For a new feature i needed a new way to identify a HomeKit object on multiple devices, because the `.uniqueIdentifier` parameter is salted on every device.

```
import Foundation
import HomeKit

protocol Identifyable {
    func getUniqueIdentifier() -> String?
}

extension HMActionSet: Identifyable {
    func getUniqueIdentifier() -> String? {
        return self.name.toBase64()
    }
}
```

I created a swift protocol and made an **extension** to HMActionSet. Of course now that i found the error it looks stupid, to **name the method like a getter**. But this should not be the discussion now. It seems like this methods **overrides** the attribute of HMActionSet. When executing the actionSet internal functions accidentally use the wrong uniqueIdentifier, therefore the error is correct. (No object found).

```
/*!
 * @brief A unique identifier for the action set.
 */
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
open var uniqueIdentifier: UUID { get }
```

If i name the method `func uniqueIdentifier() -> String?` Xcode immediately shows me a warning.

```
Method 'uniqueIdentifier()' with Objective-C selector 'uniqueIdentifier' conflicts with getter for 'uniqueIdentifier' with the same Objective-C selector
```

As i know HomeKit is written in Objective-C. I am using swift 4.

## My questions to you:

- Why are there no compiler errors (`getUniqueIdentifier()`)?
- If its a runtime problem mixing a swift extension into a objective-c framework, why does it only occur when reentering the app and not at the first start or later?

Looking forward to read your explanations about the problem that stole my sleep. :)